# CORS Error using Angular and Yii2 on POST Request

Tags: php, angular, yii2, cors

I am creating a project using Angular as frontend and using Yii2 for the API. It doesn't have any problems for GET request. I can fetch the the data smoothly. The problem is when I want to have a POST request. I check the request in network tab of chrome dev tools and I saw two request: one with CORS Error status and one with 405.

Here's my code:

**Frontend (Angular)**

```
addRecipe(recipe: Recipe) {
  this.http
    .post('https://the-url-to-my-api', recipe, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
      })
    })
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
}
```

**Yii2 Class and Functions**

```
class RecipeController extends ActiveController
{
    public function actions() {
        $actions = parent::actions();

        unset(
            $actions[ 'index' ],
            $actions[ 'create' ],
            $actions[ 'update' ],
            $actions[ 'delete' ]
        );


        return $actions;
    }

    protected function verbs()
    {
        return [
            'index' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
            'view' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
            'create' => ['POST'],
            'update' => ['POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH'],
            'delete' => ['DELETE'],
            'login' => ['POST'],
            'find' => ['GET'],
        ];
    }
```

**Yii2 Behaviours**

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    // remove authentication filter
    $auth = $behaviors['authenticator'];
    unset($behaviors['authenticator']);

    // add CORS filter
    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
        // 'cors' => [
        //     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => ['http://localhost:4200'],
        //     'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['OPTIONS', 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
        //     'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
        //     'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
        //     'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 86400,
        //     'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => [],
        // ]
    ];

    // re-add authentication filter
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = $auth;
    // avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
    $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options'];

    return $behaviors;
}
```

**Yii2 htaccess**

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'http://localhost:4200'
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
```

I have checked everywhere and tried many things but I still got that CORS Error. Is there something that I missing in server side?

Answer (score 0):

Please configure CORS for yii in behaviors and please ensure that the `OPTIONS` action/verb is allowed. You should add it like here

```
'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
```

See also the docs here: [CORS config](https://github.com/sirinibin/Yii2-RESTful-API-with-OAuth2/blob/master/backend/controllers/RestController.php)

i.e:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
        'cors' => [
            'Origin' => ['*'],
            'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
            'Allow' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => null,
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 86400,
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => []
        ]

    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is problem with your backend(Yii2).
Try with this code

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
        'cors' => [
            'Origin' => ['*'],
            // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => ['*'],
            'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => null,
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 86400,
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => []
        ]

    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```